# How to seed the database after deployment with user input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, capistrano3

I want to seed the database with secret data after deployment, like name and email of the admin. I wrote the following in the file db/seeds/production/admin.seeds.rb:

```
STDOUT.puts "Enter e-mail for admin:"
email = STDIN.gets.strip.downcase

STDOUT.puts "Enter password for admin:"
pw = STDIN.gets.strip

STDOUT.puts "Re-enter password for admin:"
pwc = STDIN.gets.strip

u = User.create(email: email, password: pw, password_confirmation: pwc, 
   name: "Administrator", capabilities:"admin")
if u.save
   STDOUT.puts "Admin account created!"
else
   STDOUT.puts "Something went wrong!"
end
```

But when I call

```
cap production rails:rake:db:seed
```

I get just the first line "Enter e-mail for admin:", I entered the email and clicked enter but nothing happens as if the console doesn't recognize any thing.

How can I seed the database with my secret data using the console?

Versions: capistrano 3.4.1, rails 5.0.1, ruby 2.4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got stuck there for long time without any solution.

Then I solved the problem be adding these information **manually** on my production database. So that I don't need to enter any thing while seeding.

For other seed files, I just call

```
cap production rails:rake:db:seed
```

Which seeds all files saved in production directory.

I hope this workaround solution could help someone.